# Return a set containing words that are in text_file1 but are not in text_file2

Tags: python, python-3.x

As title says, I'm trying to write a function that reads 2 text files and return the distinct words that are in file 1 and are not in file 2. The main problem I can't work around is the fact that punctuation within words makes them different from one another, "little" and "little!" are 2 different words for my program. I've tried with the .replace() method but there's definitely something I'm doing wrong

```
def wsub(fn1, fn2):
    parole_risultato = []
    parole_testo1 = []
    parole_testo2 = []
    with open(fn1, 'r', encoding='UTF-8-SIG') as x:
        testo1 = x
        for linea1 in testo1:
            for parola1 in linea1.split():
                for carattere1 in parola1:
                    if carattere1.isalpha() == False:
                        parola1.replace(carattere1, ' ')
                parola1 = parola1.lower()
                parole_testo1.append(parola1)
    with open(fn2, 'r', encoding='UTF-8-SIG') as y:
        testo2 = y
        for linea2 in testo2:
            for parola2 in linea2.split():
                for carattere2 in parola2:
                    if carattere2.isalpha() == False:
                        parola2.replace(carattere2, ' ')
                parola2 = parola2.lower()
                parole_testo2.append(parola2)
    for elemento1 in parole_testo1:
        if elemento1 not in parole_testo2:
            parole_risultato.append(elemento1)
    return set(parole_risultato), len(set(parole_risultato))
```

I can't import any libraries to do this exercise.

The result is set of words that still contains punctuation, making it very long when it shouldn't.

Comment: Don't replace punctuation signs by a space, but by an empty string `''`.

Comment: And note that `replace` doesn't replace in-place, but returns a new string - which you don't use.

Comment: Ah nice, I didn't know that, and how do I use the new string created by replace? @ThierryLathuille

Comment: Assign it to the variable you want.

Comment: Why can't you import anything? The built-in modules are there to help you

Comment: It's an exercise for uni, I think they want us to understand how the modules work before using them

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions to extract words. Convert all chars to lowercase, using `lower()`. Use `set`s and a simple `set1 - set2` will give you the difference.

```
import re

filename1 = "file1.txt"
filename2 = "File2.txt"

with open(filename1, "r") as fp:
    set1 = set(word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\w+', fp.read()))

with open(filename2, "r") as fp:
    set2 = set(word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\w+', fp.read()))

difference = set1 - set2
print(difference)
```

And if you are not allowed to use `re` module (sigh), you can do the same using str.translate, as @Codist pointed out.

```
filename1 = "file1.txt"
filename2 = "File2.txt"

tr = str.maketrans({p: '' for p in "!.,;:'\"()"})

with open(filename1, "r") as fp:
    set1 = set(word.lower().translate(tr) for word in fp.read().split())

with open(filename2, "r") as fp:
    set2 = set(word.lower().translate(tr) for word in fp.read().split())

difference = set1 - set2
print(difference)
```

Comment: I can't import anything unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Once you've identified characters that you consider to represent punctuation then you can use *maketrans* and *translate* functions that are built in to the *str* type.

For example:

```
PUNCTUATION = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
TRANS = str.maketrans({p: '' for p in PUNCTUATION})

def wsub(*filenames):
    assert len(filenames) == 2
    sl = []
    for filename in filenames:
        s = set()
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="UTF-8-SIG") as f:
            for line in f:
                for word in line.split():
                    s.add(word.translate(TRANS))
        sl.append(s)
    return sl[0] - sl[1]

print(wsub("fn1.txt", "fn2.txt"))
```